# VLOOKUP - IF Statement - Column Compare - YES or NO result desired

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010, vlookup

Last question was answered so quickly & accurately, I figured I'd give it another go!

So in Column A, there's a list of Magazine names.  In Column C there's a list of Advertiser's names.  Magazine titles & Advertiser names may repeat like so...

Time Magazine (Column A) ........ Amazon (Column C)
Time Magazine (Column A) ........ Amazon (Column C)
Forbes (Column A) ........ Google (Column C)
Forbes (Column A) ........ Amazon (Column C)

On a separate sheet in cell A1 I have a Data Validation drop down with the names of Advertiser's from Column C mentioned before.

I'm looking to input a formula which will lookup the Advertiser's name selected by the data validation drop down & tell me YES or NO to whether their name is ever associated with a specific magazine title in Column A, such as Forbes.

So in the example above, I'd want to be able to select the Advertiser "Google" from my data validation drop down & see a YES, indicating to me they do advertise in Forbes.

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: On the 2nd sheet, what cell address is the dropdown and what address is the magazine name?

Comment: The cell address for the drop down is A1 & the the magazine names (on a different sheet) start at A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(MAX(INDEX((Sheet1!A2:A99=A2)*(Sheet1!C2:C99=$A$1),,)),"Yes","No")
```

Assumptions:

- This formula will be used in a cell on the 2nd sheet.
- Sheet with raw data is named `Sheet1`. Change the formula appropriately.
- Raw data extends no further than row 99; change the 99s in the formula as appropriate.
- Raw data start in row 2.
- On the sheet with the drop-down, the drop-down is in cell A1. Change as appropriate.
- On the sheet with the drop-down, the magazine you wish to check the advertiser against is in cell A2. Change as appropriate.

Comment: @AnthonyOlivieri Were you able to get this to work? I'm here to help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I'm trying to get it to work now but for some reason I'm unable to, I'm getting "No" for every selection.  -- Maybe I should go about doing this a different way?

Comment: This is a good method. I can sort it for you immediately if you can send me the workbook. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you! I'll send a small sample of data along for you to see & I much appreciate the help.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to use A2:A99 over A:A?

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer Yes indeed. Entire column references should never be used unless as parameters for functions that are designed for them... like SUMIFS(). Such references would create a huge amount of extra work for Excel with no benefit.

Comment: I had no idea, thanks! Is there a "good" way to tell Excel to, say take all of the data in column A until it reaches an empty cell? (in other words, if I am using cells A2:A20, and then I fill A:26, do I have to edit my function, or is there a more robust way?

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer You will need to edit the references in that case. HOWEVER, there is a technique often called 'dynamic ranges' that you can use instead of the hard-coded range. These are actually formulas that evaluate to the range you need based on the current size of the data. These formulas are stored in the Name Manager and used in place of the hard range. This solves the problem of continuously needing to update the references as the size of the data changes. Read my article:  http://blog.excelhero.com/2011/03/21/the_imposing_index/